# Problem with Linefeeds in C#

Tags: c#, clearquest

I use `System.Environment.NewLine` to add a line feed between lines. This is in a C# dll. This dll uses **IBM RATIONAL CLEARQUEST** API's to insert into **Oracle** database these values. **CLEARQUEST** is setup in a Linux box and I am not sure under which OS the **Oracle** is setup.

Point is the `System.Environment.NewLine` i use in concatination (with + operator on string) does not work. The text comes as continuous string.

How can i realize the line breaks in C#. I tried with `\r\n` but same result.

has any one faced this problem? I am not sure if the platform could be a factor here

Comment: the linebreak disappears after you read data from the database, or is it absent before data is sent to the db?

Comment: it is present when its sent to DB i can see that when i put a Breakpoint. not sure what is happening. Another point is the data sent to DB is via the IBM CQ API's

Comment: I see you mentioned it's present when sent to the DB as observed through a breakpoint - if you're still in C# (especially in your code), that makes sense. Can you see the actual insert query being performed by CQ via a DB profiler? It may very well be that it's not escaping characters as expected...

Comment: I will see if that could be possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
string CRLF = "\x0d\x0a";
```

And use that instead of `Environment.Newline`.

source http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21120820